# Как правильно работать с данными в подобном случае?

Tags: php

Делаю интернет магазин на архитектуре MVC. Есть ссылка в формате:

```
site.com/категория/подкатегория
```

Есть контроллер `categoryController@actionIndex`:

```
public function actionIndex($parentCategory, $childrenCategory = false) {
       //находим категорию в базе данных
        $category = Category::getCategoryById($parentCategory);
        if ($category) {
            //если категория есть, смотрим, есть ли в ссылке 2 параметр
            if ($childrenCategory) {
                //если есть, то ищем дочернюю категорию в базе данных
                $childCategory = Category::getCategoryById($childrenCategory);
                if ($childCategory['parent_id'] == $category['id']) {
                    //если находим, выводим вьюху для категорий
                } else {
                    //иначе выдаем 404 ошибку.
                    Scripts::set404();
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Дочерней категории нет, все окей';
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

В данном контроллере есть 2 запроса к БД: 1 - ищем по названию родительскую категорию, 2 - ищем дочернюю

Вопрос: что будет более быстро работать и меньше нагружать сервер: 2 отдельных запроса к БД или 1 запрос с оператором `WHERE caterogy.name IN (*перечисляем названия категорий*)`, а затем уже преобразуем данные из массива о родительской и дочерней категории?

Comment: один запрос конечно быстрее выполнится чем два.

Comment: в данном случае лучше второй запрос сразу ограничить с `parent_id`, тем более что потенциально названия подкатегорий могут и дублироваться.

Comment: а, там тип id передается, а не название? тогда нет смысла в `parent`

Comment: @teran видимо все-таки передается название, как как в коде есть $category['id'], отредактировал свой ответ. Метод getCategoryById просто ввел в заблуждение, логичнее если бы он назывался getByName().

Comment: @Firepro да, я из за сравнения id и подумал что название,  не посмотрел на название метода + вид урл

Comment: можно обойтись без `where .. in(foo, bar)` и просто объединить таблицу категорий саму с собой. внутри блока from например достать родительскую, а в join'е дочернюю. будет чуть быстрее чем in и исключит коллизии в случае если у вас две дочерние категории имеют одинаковое название, но разного родителя (в этом случае ваш запрос вернул бы более 2х строк).

Comment: Да поставьте вы magento и не парьтесь.

Comment: @Lexx918 джойн быстрее чем `in`? почему?

Answer (score 1):

### Чем меньше обращений к базе, тем лучше, но не всегда

**Определенно**, 1 запрос работает быстрее, чем 2, как это заметил @nick_n_a, хоть и не во всех случаях. Если запрос перебирает много данных и данные не помещаются в память, то вероятно 2 запроса будут работать быстрее одного из-за меньшего количества операций с диском.

**В вашем случае, действительно правильно использовать 1 запрос, если требуются 2 записи, но это не критично**

Ведь если база данных находится рядом с приложением и таблица не большая, вы существенной разницы не заметите, если будете использовать 1 запрос вместо двух, так как вы делаете запрос по индексу (у вас же name - INDEX?), а индекс позволяет быстро позволит достать нужную запись из таблицы. Задержки на соединение и на получение данных у Вас практический отсутствуют. Дополнительная 1 мс не сыграет роли в ответе для пользователя.

Другое дело, если база данных находится не в одном дата-центре или таблица очень большая и название не помещается в индекс, то обязательно надо использовать 1 запрос вместо двух, так как появляются задержки на соединение или перебор данных.

### Кэш

Чаще всего, подобные запросы связанные с получением редко изменяемых данных, но часто запрашиваемых данных по индексу, то их стараются кэшировать, чтобы сократить количество обращений к записи в базе данных.

Применяйте кеширование при выполнении подобных запросов и вы уменьшите лишнюю нагрузку на базу данных.